# Subtracting in dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I was updating a stored procedure to change the reporting time to clients timezone. The stored procedure is comprised of a dynamic SQL, which contains the time @timeoffset parameter of smallint data type.

```
  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'SELECT DISTINCT cl.ClientId, 
  CASE WHEN DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)+', x.changedate) >= '''+ CONVERT(varchar, @start_date) +''' 
  AND DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)+', x.changedate) < '''+ CONVERT(varchar, @end_date_plus1) +''' 
  THEN DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)+',x.changedate)'
```

To change the time to the clients' time zone, I need to subtract the @timeoffset. Making it negative doesn't change the output. 
Trying to add the (-) before the conversion, would raises an error as subtraction operator is invalid for varchar. Writing it 
without the conversion raises an error 
*'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type smallint.*

Can anyone assist me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the section with CHAR(2),@timeoffset, it seems it only comes up with @t, so the value is null since it is not declared.

Comment: Yes, it comes with the whole part though. When I omit the convert, it asks to declare @timeoffset, which is already declared above.

Comment: can you paste the whole output of @sql when computed?

Comment: The code provided in the question can be written without dynamic SQL. Is there a good reason for you to use dynamic SQL in this situation?

Comment: Sure. It is because of the sources. The clients have specific databases, and the data is retrieved from the corresponding databases. I have shared just part of the select statement for simplicity purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the negative number as another variable:

```
DECLARE @neg INT = -1;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT DISTINCT cl.ClientId, 
CASE WHEN DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)*@neg+', x.changedate) >= '''+ 
CONVERT(varchar, @start_date) +''' 
AND DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)*@neg+', x.changedate) < '''+ 
CONVERT(varchar, @end_date_plus1) +''' 
THEN DATEADD(HOUR,'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset)*@neg+',x.changedate)'
```

Comment: Thanks. But ....DATEADD(HOUR,-'+CONVERT(CHAR(2),@timeoffset) seems making it negative. Upon any trouble, I'll consider yours.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a few problems in the code you've posted:

1. You are declaring `@Sql` as `varchar(max)`, but you are using the `N` prefix before setting it's value. You only need that when dealing with unicode data (`nchar` ,`nvarcar`). This is critical but you should be aware of this.
2. You are using `convert` without specifying the `style` parameter. It's not that bad when converting ints to strings, but it can cause unexpected behaviors when dealing with dates. Whenever you need to use string representation for date/datetime values, you should always use the ISO8601 standard, since it's guaranteed that Sql server will always convert it to date correctly, regardless of local settings. To convert a `datetime` value to ISO8061 standard, use style 126 in the `convert` statement.
3. You are using `varchar` without specifying the length. This is a bad habit since SQL Server have different default values to the length depending on context. It's 1 when declaring a variable, but 30 when used in `cast` and `convert`.

I've done some changes to your code, including changing the `char(2)` you've used to `varchar(11)` (because 11 chars will contain even the minimum value of the int data type which is -2147483648) for the `@timeoffset` parameter, and had no problems with it being negative.

Here is my test:

```
DECLARE @timeOffset int = -10, 
        @start_date datetime = getdate(), 
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 
N'SELECT '''+ convert(char(23), @start_date, 126) +''' As GetDate, 
       DATEADD(HOUR, '+ CAST(@timeOffset as varchar(11)) +', '''+ convert(char(23), @start_date, 126) +''') As DateAdd';

SELECT @Sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

Results:

```
SELECT '2018-11-08T20:33:31.670' As GetDate, 
       DATEADD(HOUR, -10, '2018-11-08T20:33:31.670') As DateAdd

GetDate                     DateAdd
2018-11-08T20:33:31.670     08.11.2018 10:33:3
```

Comment: Thank you for the good feedback. However, the @timeoffset is not a datetime data type. It is just the offset value to the time zone, so it will be an integer number. I'm forced to convert it to char(2) just because using the int is raising an error.

Comment: 1. I was referring to the `CONVERT(varchar, @start_date)` you have in your code. 2. You are forced to convert `@timeoffset` to a string, but it doesn't have to be `char(2)`, it can be `varchar(11)` like in my example.